# Looking for the name of a children's book about hobbit-like people

Tags: identification-request

I read this book (in English) 10+ years ago at a library and now I can not for the life of me remember the title.

#### Plot things that I remember

For the first book:

- In the first book, there are two groups of hobbit-like people.
- The first group live like us in houses and have schools.
- The second group all live together in one group under a tree (I believe)

  - This group has horrible names, like Grub.
- One member of the second group is a young girl who tricks a boy from the first into believing she's part of his group.

For the second book:

- One of the boys meets a human boy

  - This is bad because humans cannot usually see them.
- There is also a scene where the boy from the first book is standing near a pond in a cave. He talks to someone on the other side who he thinks is the young girl. He asks what colour her bedroom is. The voice says yellow, but that is wrong because she always says it's blue with yellow.

That's all I really remember, I think there was something about clocks in the second book but I'm not sure. I've tried looking in the library where I first read it but I think it may have been removed.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please add which language your read this? And do you remember anything about the book cover?

Comment: I'm getting nowhere with yellow (bed)rooms, blue with/and yellow, Grub, under/below/beneath (a) tree/trees, cave, pond/pool in cave... Do you think it was a recent book ten years ago? More suitable for younger or older children? Can you remember any of the other characters' names?

Comment: I'd say the age group would be around 10-13? I don't think it was a recent book, and i can't remember any other names.

Comment: British? American? Canadian...?

Comment: British I think.

Comment: @Katie in what sense were the characters hobbit-like?

Comment: I said hobbit in the sense that they were smaller than humans. I couldnt think of another word to describe them...

Comment: *The Minnipins* aka *The Gammage Cup* is a famous children's novel about hobbit-like people, British, and the first of a two-book series. I haven't read it, but [the Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gammage_Cup) sounds nothing like your description, so I think that's not the one you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, its not the minnipins. I had looked at that before but it wasnt that.

Comment: The Borrowers comes to mind for me, but there are no characters named Grub, and only one character who lives under a tree. I also don't recall there being a cave pond scene. Still looking!

Comment: Yeh def not the borrowers.